# Rails Won't Render My View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm running devise with custom views, and my `login` page was rendering perfectly before, but I just changed the name of the model from `human` to `user`, renamed the controller and the views, but it just refuses to render my view.

I don't get an error, my layout renders perfectly, but it doesn't yield the body for some reason.

**Code**

Here's my `routes.rb` for `Users`:

```
  ## devise controllers for users
  devise_for :user, controllers: {
    confirmations: 'user/confirmations',
    passwords: 'user/passwords',
    registrations: 'user/registrations',
    sessions: 'user/sessions',
    unlocks: 'user/unlocks',
    # commenting the below because omniauth gem isn't installed
    # omniauth_callbacks: 'user/omniauth_callbacks'
  }, skip: [:sessions]
  ## custom routes for users
  as :user do
    get 'login' => 'user/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'user/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'user/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'register' => 'user/registrations#new', as: :register
  end
```

Here's my `sessions_controller` generated by devise:

```
class User::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  ...

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    super
  end
  ...
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<%= render layout: 'layouts/shared/left_logo_panel' do %>
  <%= form_for(resource, html: {class: 'form'}, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, class:'form-control', autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, class:'form-control', autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
    <% end -%>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Log in", class:'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<% end %>
```

**Log**

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-21 04:48:13 -0700
Processing by User::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (5.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/shared/_left_logo_panel.html.erb (9.4ms)
  Rendered user/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_ga.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 39.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my layout, I'd swapped `yield` with `yield :body`, and forgot. Okay, i'm a fool. Check your layouts, guys!